# WordPress plugins wp_enque_script()

Tags: wordpress

so i'm developing my first WordPress plugin and i am having some difficulties...
I am doing it Object Oriented...
In the bottom, when 'plugins_loaded', i Create a new instance of myClass. It also enques a javascript, everytime any page is loaded. This script registration works, because i get a console.log every page load. It then registers an action on 'publish_post' that is fired when an admin publishes(saves) a new post and invokes my publish_post() method.
The method is called, when a post is published; i know it because if i uncomment it's two first lines, the sctipt dies with my var_dump.
My problem is that wp_enque_script() is not working in this method. For some reason my script isn't called...
Here's the code:

```
<?php
class myClass{  
    function __construct(){     
        // hooks & filters..
        add_action( 'publish_post', array($this, 'publish_post'));
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'plugin', //$handle
             plugins_url('/js/plugin.js', __FILE__)//$src
        );
    }

    function publish_post(){
        //global $wp_query;
        //die(var_dump($wp_query));
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'publish', //$handle
             plugins_url('/js/publish.js', __FILE__)//$src
        );
    }
}
/* Initialise outselves */
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $myObject; $myObject = new myClass;' ));
?>
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. You have to add it to a hook, for example the init (I tried with admin_head hook but that didn't work so I picked init because I saw it in another plugin. And it seem to work fine for me)

In you construct add:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'loadMyScripts'));
```

and in the function called by the action:

```
public function loadMyScripts()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 
            'publish', //$handle
             plugins_url('/js/publish.js', __FILE__)//$src
        );

}
```